# PHP HTML Iframe not show

Tags: php, iframe

I have `<iframe>` tag.

I tried to display it :

Code 1

```
<iframe src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/wpst_4m_c-E?feature=oembed' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

The actual code:

```
<iframe src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/wpst_4m_c-E?feature=oembed' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

I tested Code 1, but it won't display the video. It show the code.

Code 2

```
<iframe src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/wpst_4m_c-E?feature=oembed' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

I tested Code 2, it display correctly.

My question, why Code 1 couldn't display the video?

Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in `code 1`, you are using HTML entity names instead of the actual character. For example `<` becomes `&lt;`

As a result, your browser displays the code as plain text, instead of realizing that it's HTML code and rendering it.

You can find a list of HTML entity names [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html)

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe width="420" height="345"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is happening becoz u r using html entities in the first code, and html entities are only used to display text characters, not for browsers

Comment: Please explain your answer a bit.